# How to add Proxy pass, Reverse proxy pass to my apache virtual host configuration?

Tags: apache, apache2, cpanel, vps, whm

I am working on a VPS fully managed server. Many applications are running on it. For one of my domains, I want to pass a proxy to it. I did ssh and found the below information from the /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

```
To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/user/domain.com/*.conf"
```

I created a conf file in this directory and added the below config.

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
    <Location "/">
        ProxyPass unix:/run/gunicorn.sock|http://localhost/
        ProxyPassReverse unix:/run/gunicorn.sock|http://localhost/
    </Location>
</IfModule>
```

After rebuilding and restarting the apache, nothing happening. please help me on it.